# Fill minimum shape that encloses a set of points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've a 2D numpy array initialized to 0 and I've picked 4 points in that array. I want to interpolate values between them to create a closed shape and fill that shape with value 1. Here's the code

```
a = np.zeros((256, 256))
depth = np.random.randint(50, 200)
corner1 = np.random.randint(0, 100)
corner2 = np.random.randint(150, 250)
top_max = depth - np.random.randint(10, 25)
bottom_max = depth + np.random.randint(10, 25)
top_max_loc = np.random.randint(corner1 + 10, corner2 - 10)
bottom_max_loc = np.random.randint(corner1 + 10, corner2 - 10)

left_point = (depth, corner1)
right_point = (depth, corner2)
top_point = (top_max, top_max_loc)
bottom_point = (bottom_max, bottom_max_loc)

a[left_point] = 1
a[right_point] = 1
a[top_point] = 1
a[bottom_point] = 1
print(left_point)
print(right_point)
print(top_point)
print(bottom_point)
```

and here's the plot of the points

[image]

What I am looking for is to fill the array with some random shape and get results as follows (just the yellow colored shape)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) given a set of points, i.e the smallest shape that encloses them all. For that you can use [`skimage.morphology.convex_hull_image`](http://devdoc.net/python/scikit-image-doc-0.13.1/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.convex_hull_image). Since you have only one shape, you can reduce the search to the bounding box of the set of points. For multiple objects you might be interested in [`convex_hull_object`](http://devdoc.net/python/scikit-image-doc-0.13.1/api/skimage.morphology.html#convex-hull-object).

Here's an example generated with your code:

```
from skimage.morphology import convex_hull_image

x,y = np.where(a)
x_min, x_max = x.min(), x.max()
y_min, y_max = y.min(), y.max()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(a[x_min:x_max+1, y_min:y_max+1])
```

[image]

Now obtain the convex hull of the sliced image, and assign back to the array with:

```
a[x_min:x_max+1, y_min:y_max+1] = convex_hull_image(a[x_min:x_max+1, y_min:y_max+1])
```

Resulting in:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(a)
```

[image]